# Android Emulator - Intent.createChooser says "No application can perform this action" while opening it for pdf type documents

Tags: android, pdf, android-intent, android-emulator

I need to ask the **user to select a pdf document** from device internal/external memory below is the code i am using. **It works on real device but not works on Emulator**. **I have installed the Pdf Viewer on the Emulator.**

It throws no error but displays the message box window saying **"No application can perform this action"**

```
     Intent intent = new Intent();
     intent.setType("pdf/*");
     //intent.setType("application/pdf");
     intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);


     try {
         Intent pdfIntent = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select pdf");
         startActivityForResult(pdfIntent, SELECT_PDF_DIALOG);
 } 
 catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
     CommonMethods.ShowMessageBox(this, "No Application Available to View PDF.");
 }
 catch(Exception e)
 {
     CommonMethods.ShowMessageBox(this, e.toString());
 }
```

I need this code to work on the Emulator because i can not check/test the full functionality of my application.

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

This is because Android doesn't provide any inbuilt functionality to read `.pdf` extension. So, you have to install any third party Application for reading `.pdf`(Any PDF Viewer) to make it working.

Ok then try this one,

Keep your PDF file in SDCard and try to execute it with this stuff,

```
            File file = new File("/sdcard/Android.pdf");

            if (file.exists()) {
                Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

                try {
                    startActivity(intent);
                } 
                catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(YourActivity.this, 
                        "No Application Available to View PDF", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
```

Comment: I have installed Adobe Reader on the Emulator & i can view Adobe documents through it.

Comment: Sorry for late reply its because of loadshedding here... I tried the above code & it says "No Application Available to View PDF"..

Comment: well that means you had an exception `ActivityNotFoundException` which means you haven't installed any application to read PDF.

Comment: I have installed "Adobe Reader" & i can open the pdf documents using it. But it not works for me in code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install some pdf viewer on your device or emulator to make this work.

Comment: Thanks. I have installed the pdf viewer on the emulator.